# Custom convolution kernel and toroidal convolution in PyTorch

Tags: padding, convolution, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to do two things with a PyTorch convolution which aren't mentioned in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/conv.html) or code:

1. I want to create a convolution with a fixed kernel like this:

   ```
   000010000
   000010000
   100010001
   000010000
   000010000
   ```

   The horizontal aspect is like dilation, I guess, but the vertical part is different. I see that dilation is available as a parameter in the code, but it has to be a scalar or single-element tuple (not one element per dimension), so I don't think it can do what I want here.
2. I would like my convolutions to "wrap around" like a toroid, rather than use padding.

   *EDIT TO ADD:* I see that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6124) for this , which also provides a suboptimal [workaround](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3858). So, I guess that there's no "right" way to do it, yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Unlike [`torch.nn.conv2d()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#convolution-layers) (which instantiates its own trainable kernel), [`torch.nn.functional.conv2d()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) takes as parameters both your matrix and kernel, so you can pass it whatever custom kernel you want.
2. As suggested by [@zou3519](https://github.com/zou3519) in a [Github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3858#issuecomment-347341908) (linked to the [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6124) you mentioned yourself), you could implement yourself a 2D circular padding by "*repeating the tensor in a nxn grid, then cropping out the part you need.*":

```python
def circular_pad_2d(x, pad=(1, 1)):
   # Snipped by @zou3519 (https://github.com/zou3519)
   return x.repeat(*x_shape[:2])[
        (x.shape[0]-pad[0]):(2*x.shape[0]+pad[0]), 
        (x.shape[1]-pad[1]):(2*x.shape[1]+pad[1])
   ]

# Example:
x = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
y = circular_pad_2d(x, pad=(2, 3))
print(y)
#     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
#     4     5     6     4     5     6     4     5     6
#     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
#     4     5     6     4     5     6     4     5     6
```

---

2. ***(previous)*** In the `torch.nn.functional` module too, [`torch.nn.functional.pad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=pad#torch.nn.functional.pad) can take as parameter `mode=reflect`, which is what you want I believe (?). You could use this method to manually pad your input matrix before performing the convolution. *(note: you also have the [`torch.nn.ReflectionPad2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.ReflectionPad2d) layer specifically tailored for fixed 2D padding by reflection)*

Comment: Thanks! 1. I didn't realise this distinction between trainable and not. That helps a lot. In torch.nn.functional.conv2d(), if I understand right, `filters` is the custom kernel? 2. Toroidal is different from reflecting, see eg https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6124 - it seems to be an open request, not currently possible except with a workaround.

Comment: 1. Yes, give your kernel as *filter* (defined by the parameter `weights`). 2. Ah indeed, my bad. What about the workaround mentioned in this issue, i.e. implementing 2D circular padding yourself, to apply it to your matrix before convolution? (I updated my answer accordingly)

Comment: Yes, I had linked to it in my edit -- it does seem to be regarded as a workaround. It'll do for now.

Comment: It looks like [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pad) now support `circular` padding.